# The Method is deprecated "palette.generate" From android support library

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-support-library

When i was update my workplace sdks. iam getting warning of this line.

```
Palette.GenerateAsync(bitmap)
```

***Method Android.Support.Graphics.V7.Palette.Generate is deprecated message*** ,so which is best way to generate palette..

**NOTE:**

*Java Code also welcome*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `Palette.Builder()` instead to create a `Palette`. Like:

```
var palette = Palette.Builder(bitmap).GenerateAsync();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// Generate palette synchronously and return it
public Palette createPaletteSync(Bitmap bitmap) {
  Palette p = Palette.from(bitmap).generate();
  return p;
}

// Generate palette asynchronously and use it on a different
// thread using onGenerated()
public void createPaletteAsync(Bitmap bitmap) {
  Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new PaletteAsyncListener() {
    public void onGenerated(Palette p) {
      // Use generated instance
    }
  });
}
```

[You can see here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/palette-colors)

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin lamba:

Palette.from(bitmap).generate {

}